# Gradle Error: Colliding Attributes when creating Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

when building an .apk file for Android in Unity with the Wikitude SDK I always get the Error: Gradle Error: Colliding Attributes.
I hope someone had the same problem or can solve this, because I really don't know what to do.
I would be very happy if someone could help me here!

I use Unity 2019.3.6f1 and Wikitude SDK Expert Edition for Unity 9.0.
Attached is the error log with the error itself and a video of the development process in unity, if this helps (see link*).

Thanks in advance! :)

Best regards,
Sebastian

*Link for the video: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlxZ4c5bmzbug_MUntWtUsJlufLlrg

Error Message:

[image: Gradle Error 1]

[image: Gradle Error 2]

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there are multiple conflicting settings for that attribute in you project.  To get around this you will need to edit your AndroidManifest.xml file in your Plugins/Android folder.

If you look at the logs it will tell you a "Suggestion" on how to fix it.  Just go add that override for the attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: thank you very much, i already tried this, but it didn't work. I just switched to an older version of untiy and now it works!